# Is there a good resource monitoring tool in linux?

Tags: monitoring, cpu

I've been looking for a good resource monitor in linux for a couple of hours and all I have found is [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/).

Specifically I've been looking for something to monitor my core clock speeds. I've found this

```
watch -n 0.1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i mhz"
```

but there must be a better way to do it.

The problem I had with conky is that you have to dig for a config that serves your needs (or write it your self) and I could find anything that showed individual cpu cores' clock speed.

When I started looking for it I was thinking about something like [cpu-z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html). I didn't think it would be this hard to find something decent - linux being the king of servers and all.

Comment: How about adding that command to your conky config file?

Comment: I find that the CPU speed can vary a couple of times per second; how do you imagine you can track every variation of speed? If you're monitoring too much then the high CPU speed you see is probably *because* of your monitoring...

Answer (score 0):

Give a second chance to conky, found this article on the interwebs:

https://mylinuxramblings.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/how-to-configure-the-conky-system-monitor/